# getting typeError while calling function

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting error - TypeError: updateAPI is not a functionn I am not sure why this is happening

the code for the function is as below

```
var APIS = '<?=preg_replace("/'/", "\'", json_encode($apis))?>';
var APISP = $.parseJSON(APIS);

var changedTo = 'left';
var updateAPI = function(id)
{
    /* Function Statements */
};
```

The code through which I am calling this function is

```
window.setInterval(function() {
var ele = document.getElementById('itemSelector');
updateAPI((ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].id).replace(/[_\D]+/, ''));
}, 100);
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of escape character is wrong. It is evident even after seeing the formatting of your question done by StackOverflow. You have used forward slash (`/`) instead of backward slash (`\`). Hence, `var updateAPI` is included in that string and `updateAPI` is undefined.
Try this:

```
var APIS = '<?=preg_replace("\'/", "\'", json_encode($apis))?>';
```

OR maybe depending on what regular expression you want, you might want this:

```
var APIS = '<?=preg_replace("/\'/", "\'", json_encode($apis))?>';
```